# ¿Cómo guardar texto en portapapeles? Safari IOS 10

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari

Tengo un input `url` que tiene como `value` asignado un valor **X**. Al apretarse un botón en la misma página con ID `copy` se copiará el valor de `url` al portapapeles.

El siguiente código no me ha funcionado:

```
document.getElementById('copy').onclick = function() {
    var url = document.getElementById('url');
    url.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    alert('Copied to Clipboard');
}
```

Simplemente no lo guarda en portapapeles.
Usando Safari, iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente opino no se puede en IOS.

Se pueden consultar las posiblidades según sistemas operativos y navegadores en: http://caniuse.com

En este caso: http://caniuse.com/#feat=clipboard

## respuesta editada

La pregunta fue editada (antes se refería a usar un botón, ahora acepta otros métodos). Según https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios sigue sin ser posible (dice más o menos los mismo que caniuse.com)

Pero si alguien encontrara una respuesta sería muy bueno.

Comment: Estoy segurísimo de que sí. Lo más probable es que mi código sea el erróneo para IOS, pero en más de una ocasión me he encontrado con un sitio con una característica similar.

Comment: @Justo, Puede ser que tengas razón, pero no hay manera de saberlo en forma precisa porque en tu post no hay ni una pregunta ni una afirmación sino una descripción de algo que no anda. Mi respuesta fue ponerte un link a la razón de por qué eso no funciona. Espero que te haya servido.

Comment: Ahora si es una pregunta

Comment: Podrías probar con https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios#answer-41267511 no se me ocurre otra idea. Los comentarios de esa respuesta parecen decir que funcionó (no debería pero parece que sí).